# Failed to install myapp.apk on device timeout

Tags: java, android

I have eagerly been trying to run my code from Eclipse on my phone. The console keeps in spitting out:

```
[2013-06-18 17:22:12 - myapp] Failed to install myapp.apk on device '*************': timeout
[2013-06-18 17:22:12 - myapp] Launch canceled!
```

This is extremely annoying and is hindering me form being productive.

I do see that this question has been asked before, however none of the solutions solve my problem.

I have tried the following:

- Restart my computer
- Restart Eclipse
- Restart my phone
- Restart the adb (from Eclipse and from the command line -
  terminal)
- Clean my project
- Delete apps from my phones internal memory
- Take USB cable out and plug it back in
- Switch USB ports
- Edit my code and recompile it
- Change the ADB connection Timeout

What is causing this error? What can I do to completely terminate it?

Comment: Tried a different usb lead?

Comment: No - would this work? If yes, I'll try and get my hands on a new cable.

Comment: Maybe, does it install when you do adb install -r package.name ?

Comment: try setting the connection via wifi to see if you have a problem with the cable.

Comment: Try what FunkTheMonk suggested.  Also verify that ADB from the commandline works at all - you say you've restarted it, but you don't say that you have successfully used ADB for anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the timeout on your eclipse

Go to window-> Preferences--> Android --> DDMS --> ADB Connection time out(ms) an put the time (milliseconds) you need.

For example,for the old Galaxy S 1 10000

Comment: Dude, please read my question thoroughly before answering. I did state that I have already tried this...

Comment: Wondering if there problem isn't actually a timeout, but an issue with the apk or the development settings on your device?

Comment: Under system settings/apps or system settings/ on your device you should be able to locate 'Developer Options'. Make sure that 'usb debugging' is enabled. On the computer you can open a terminal/command prompt and run 'adb devices' to make sure your device is actually connected via the android debug bridge. Hope this helps.